# Clausula condicional AND Mysql

Tags: mysql

Esta consulta recibe dos parámetros, lo que pretendo es que la segunda condicional participe de la consulta solo si el valor que recibe es mayor que 0, es decir que `AND fk_id_b = ?` se evalúe solo si su valor es mayor a 0. si no que la consulta termine en **WHERE fk_id_a = ?**
¿es posible?

```
SELECT * FROM tabla 
WHERE fk_id_a = ?
AND fk_id_b = ?
```

Gracias...

Comment: Es solo mysql o estas usando algun lenguaje para hacer la llamada? (php, c#, java,....)

Comment: @JoseJavierSegura asumi que solo es sql, en las etiquetas dicen solo mysql

Answer (score 2):

Solo para aclarar un poco la pregunta, voy a asignarle nombres a los 2 parámetros en vez de usar el signo de interrogación:

```
SELECT * FROM tabla 
WHERE fk_id_a = :paramA
AND fk_id_b = :paramB
```

#### Solución propuesta usando XOR

La solución propuesta por OP es:

```
SELECT * FROM tabla 
WHERE fk_id_a = :paramA
AND ((fk_id_b = :paramB AND fk_id_b > 0)
XOR (1=1))
```

Esta solución, no solamente es difícil de entender, tampoco es correcta.

[Matemáticamente, `a XOR b` equivale a: `(a AND (NOT b)) OR ((NOT a) and b)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/logical-operators.html).

Por lo que la consulta equivale a:

```
SELECT * FROM tabla 
WHERE fk_id_a = :paramA
AND (((fk_id_b = :paramB AND fk_id_b > 0) AND 1<>1)
OR  ((fk_id_b <> :paramB OR fk_id_b <= 0) AND 1=1))
```

Y debido a que las expresiones `1=1` y `1<>1` siempre evalúan a `true` y `false` respectivamente, en realidad la consulta puede simplificarse a:

```
SELECT * FROM tabla 
WHERE fk_id_a = :paramA
AND (fk_id_b <> :paramB OR fk_id_b <= 0)
```

Hasta cierto grado, puedo ver cómo la consulta pudiera dar la impresión de funcionar con números negativos, pero definitivamente va a dar resultados erróneos (hasta opuestos) para valores `paramB` positivos.

#### Consulta corregida

Si el deseo es ignorar la segunda condición en la consulta si `paramB` es cero o menor, la manera usual de hacerlo es la siguiente:

```
SELECT * FROM tabla 
WHERE fk_id_a = :paramA
AND (fk_id_b = :paramB OR :paramB <= 0)
```

Nuevamente, solo usé la sintaxis `:paramA` y `:paramB` para aclarar un poco la consulta y poder diferenciar los 2 parámetros, pero te tocará ajustar la sintaxis en tu programa para que te funcione correctamente. Adicionalmente, no hicistes ninguna mención de tener que manejar valores `null`, así que no me preocupé de este punto.

Answer (score 1):

prueba esto, en el caso de el segundo parámetro sea menor o igual  a 0 no se evaluara la condicion `fk_id_b=segundo_parametro`:

```
SELECT * FROM tabla 
WHERE fk_id_a = ? AND IF((? >0), fk_id_b = ?,TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Encontré una solución, no sé si será la más apropiada, pero al menos cumple con lo requerido:

```
SELECT * FROM tabla 
WHERE fk_id_a = ?
AND ((fk_id_b = ? AND fk_id_b > 0)
XOR (1=1))
```